# Where to keep installation programs that are usually deleted?

Tags: windows

I recently moved from one windows computer to another. There were some applications and games that were kind of a "one time offer" kind of thing so I got this zip file with all of the required things to install it.

I installed it on the original computer, but I don't know how to get it on the new computer without the installer. Transferring all the files doesn't...seem to work. You have to actually install it... From now on, I'm going to keep a copy of the installer just in case this doesn't happen again. What would be some of the easiest ways to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most give-away products include a license that is only valid during the give-away
period, meaning that they are not re-installable later on, even if you have kept
the installer.
It is usually mentioned in the give-away offer whether it includes a life-time
license or limited-time.

For making such offers portable to other computers, I would counsel using a product
such as [Sandboxie](https://www.sandboxie.com/) and install them in a virtual
sandbox, which is just a folder on the hard disk whose contents can be copied.

Using the paid version of Sandboxie allows multiple sandboxes, which is also a neat
way for testing applications in a test sandbox that can be wiped out when the give-away
is not satisfactory, without the uninstaller leaving any left-overs behind.

Comment: Will this also work with things installed from a torrent on pirate sites? ...some of my friends do this

Comment: It will work with anything and is a stronger protection than an antivirus (although a good antivirus is always essential). It prevents any changes to the real operating system, all modifications are only local to the sandbox.